# Replacing certain value in a Dataset

Tags: c#, loops, dataset

i have a dataset and i want to replace every cell that is '01/01/1754 00:00:00' with NULL.

So something like a FOR LOOP look that will loop through each row in the dataset and check if the value is '01/01/1754 00:00:00' then replace that value with 'NULL'

Thanks

Comment: please post what you have tried so far ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just scanning through every cell in the dataSet should work

```
for (int i = 0; i < sampleDataSet.Tables[0].Rows.Count; i++) 
{
    for (int j = 0; j < sampleDataSet.Tables[0].Columns.Count; j++)
    {
        if (sampleDataSet.Tables[0].Rows[i][j].ToString() == "01/01/1754 00:00:00") 
        {
            sampleDataSet.Tables[0].Rows[i][j] = "NULL";
        }
    }
}
```

If the targetted data only exist at one single column of the dataset, then the second for loop can be omitted.

Comment: Your code works but there is an error with the "NULL" part. I get error: System.FormatException: The string was not recognized as a valid DateTime. There is a unknown word starting at index 0.

Comment: If i put in a date then it works but if i put in a string then it breaks. is there any way around this? thanks

Comment: I see. That is because the type of the column is DateTime. You can thus assign DBNull.Value to it.

Comment: one last thing, you see where you have put .ToString() in the if statement. could this be changed so that it doesnt convert and just checks for a DatTime value. The column in the database is already DateTime and its uneccesary to convert it to a String...

Comment: The datatype of sampleDataSet.Tables[0].Rows[i][j] is object. Thus, if you would like to compare it with a DateTime value, you can choose not to covert it to a String. The following code will do.

sampleDataSet.Tables[0].Rows[i][j].Equals(new DateTime(1754, 1, 1))

Comment: Thank you so much, you have helped a lot. One last thing tho, if i wanted to specify a certain column for the for loop to go through instead of going through the whole grid, how would i do that? so i just want it to look at the ID COLUMN.

Comment: You can use the column name. For example, the name of the column you want to specify is called "date-of-birth", then you can write sampleDataSet.Tables[0].Rows[i]["date-of-birth"] instead.

Comment: Thanks again, everything works now. You have been a true help.

Answer (score 0):

Please try this code.It works for me in updating.

```
var dt = DataSet.Table[0] // as per your requirement;
        dt.Select(string.Format("[columnname] = '{0}' ", "datevalue")).ToList<DataRow>()
                .ForEach(r => r["columnname"] = DBNull.Value);
```

Comment: fine change it to "NULL" as mentioned in the question.

Comment: in some other logic it fails because of this null ? wt's wrong ? It should update datatable with null. I got it working . :)

Comment: Your column is DateTime in DataTable ?

Comment: yh i replaced it DBNull.Value andit worked, thanks for your help :)

Comment: yes fine.. update null with DBNull.value in my code then is it fine ?

Answer (score 0):

You mentioned a `DataSet` here, but I doubt you meant `DataTable`, try the following code:

```
foreach(DataTable dt in ds.Tables){
  foreach(DataRow row in dt.Rows){
     for(int i = 0; i < dt.Columns.Count; i++){
       if(object.Equals(row[i],"01/01/1754 00:00:00")) row[i] = null;
     }
  }
}
```